# What is best time to create and attach children?

Tags: dart

I'm making Custom Elements without polymer and I don't use HTML markup. So, to have inner elements I have to construct and attach it on runtime. MyComponent is just classic View. I can set some data `{val: 97.0, unit: '%'}` and component displays it.

All initializations I do in `attached` or `domReady` event ( I still didn't get where is the best). Here I can set data to real elements was attached ('97.0%' to the span element).

So, I can create inner elements in constructor `MyComponent.created()`, in `attached` event, in `domReady` event or ever in factory constructor like this:

```
factory MyComponent (data) {
  var component = new Element.tag('my-component');
  component.data = data;
  component.children.add(
    new Element.span()
    ..classes.toggle('display', true)
  );
  return component;
}
```

And here is a question: where is best place to:

1. construct elements with `new Element.tag('my-component');`;
2. set it's properties like style, classes and so on;
3. attach it with `children.add(component);?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a joke in that title somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean infinite loop problem? I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this doesn't matter much except I discourage the use of
`MyComponent.created()` to manipulate the DOM because this is known to cause endless loops.
If you manipulate the DOM in sync code the rendering is blocked until your code is done (no matter when you do the adding).
If you do async operations between DOM updates (fetch data from a server for instance), the browser might rerender between updates which might be expensive. I think in this case it's more efficient to wait until you have all information and do all DOM updates at once.

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/21495
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23666

Comment: So, you left me `attached` or `domeReady` events only. Ok, In this case I have to choose `attached`. Thanks.

Comment: The factory constructor is fine as well, just not the `created()` constructor.